# How to detect conflicts between branches in the bare git repository

Tags: git, github, merge, diff

Currently I need to find the conflicts(which cannot be auto resolved by git) between branches in the bare repo on the server side.

I'm trying to use `git read-tree -i -m ${merge_base} ${branch_a} ${branch_b}` to generate the index file and then read its content via `git ls-files --stage`. But it is still not sufficient to identify the conflicts of files through the stage number, because even the same line of a file is modified on both of the two branches, git still can auto resolve the conflicts if the modifications are exactly the same.

If anyone has idea to solve this issue, or knows how to make the `merge` operation with git Plumbing Commands, please let me know.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Identifying conflicts means working with content, to see which parts have changed in conflicting ways.  Content work is done in worktrees. You can implement worktrees and run merge operations using core commands, but to get a good answer to your question you'll have to identify what exactly you're after here, cloning is dirt cheap, it's built for this.  Do a local clone, do the merge, push the result. Done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `git merge-tree`.

Here's a sample of bash function that takes two branches as parameters. It outputs "conflict" if there is any conflic, otherwise "no conflict". The function is NOT robust enough.

```
function testconflict() {
    foo=$1
    bar=$2
    mergebase=$(git merge-base $foo $bar)
    if [ "$mergebase" = "" ];then
        #in case foo and bar have no common ancestor, use the empty tree as the merge base
        mergebase=4b825dc642cb6eb9a060e54bf8d69288fbee4904
    fi
    #test if the output has conflict markers of "merge" style
    git merge-tree $mergebase $foo $bar | xargs | 
        if grep -oe '<<<<<<<.*=======.*>>>>>>>';then
            echo conflict
        else
            echo no conflict
        fi 
}
```

Comment: in the second command: "git merge-base $mergebase $foo $bar" You probably meant "git merge-tree..."

Comment: This answer is exactly what I'm looking for! Thanks a lot for your help.@ElpieKay @max630

Comment: @zyang this function doesn't cover all cases. Please adjust the `grep` part. It may not work for conflicting binaries.

Comment: @ElpieKay Thanks to remind me about conflicting binaries, I'll deal this carefully. However, it seems `git merge-tree` will output all content of binary files when there is no conflict, and this might be a problem when the binary file is large. Is there any way to control the output format of `git merge-tree` command? There is so few info about this command, and the git official website even doesn't mention it in the Plumbing Commands list.

Comment: @zyang I made a test with two small binaries. The output doesn't include any content of the binaries. It just prints `warning: Cannot merge binary files: foo.img (.our vs. .their)` without conflict markers. All I know about the command is in the help document.

Answer (score 0):

I Would just check git merge otherbranch --no-ff --no-commit. Then you see what happens and you can revert in case you face a big Mess.
I would not use plumbing commands. If this is crucial just have a look
What merge does.

Comment: Also thanks for your reply @Christoph. Considering that `git merge` is not available in a bare repo, so `git merge-tree` is more helpful to me.

Comment: @zyang thanks you made me aware of the subtle difference of bare repos ;-)